# Reliability of Firebase Dynamic links in iOS?

Tags: firebase, react-native-ios, firebase-dynamic-links, react-native-firebase

How can I setup dynamic links which are robust like google maps, Twitter or WhatsApp ?
I’m using react-native-firebase v6 for my react-native iOS app

I’m using Passwordless Auth/ SignInWithEmailLink to  Authenticate my users but this completely depends upon dynamic links.

I had set this up successfully and and everything was working fine.

But now suddenly the authentication links provided in the email don’t open the app in iOS

What can be a possible workaround that the links always open in the app like Twitter or anything else.??

Because this is one of the most essential functionalities of my app as the user can’t sign up if the link doesn’t open in the app.

EDIT: Apple App site association
Below is the apple-app-site-association of my app automatically provided by Firebase, do I need to change something here??

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"4D4NYZN576.com.realyze","paths":["NOT /_/*","/*"]}]}}
```

Help would be very much appreciated.

P.S could this be a problem of Safari and the Apple Mail App?

Thanks